# Raise an error when option parameters are not delimited by comma

Tags: ruby

I want option parser to raise an error when arguments passed to an option are not separated by the correct delimiter, comma. For example, in:

```
script_name -p a b -s test
```

`a` and `b` are separated not with a comma, but with a space. I want to throw an error for this.

Is there any sophisticated way of doing it?

Comment: How are you parsing it now?

Comment: How can we answer this without knowing what are acceptable values for the arguments? Suppose, for example, the string were `"script_name -p;a,b,-s"`. Are `p` and `a` arguments separated by a semicolon (which should have been a comma), or is `p;a` a valid argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they've failed to enter commas then the additional values don't get processed.  You can check if there is more than one argument left after parsing.

If it was successfully pared, the only argument should be `["script_name"]` but if there's `["script_name", "b"]` that indicates the orphan values.

So...

```
options_parser.parse!(args)
raise "orphans found - have you forgotten commas?" if args.count > 1
```